# got segmentation error (core dumped) doing pointer operations

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, coredump

I got a segmentation error (core dumped) when trying to run the program. It's just some simple pointer operations, but I can't figure out the problem.

```
int get_address_value(int* ptr) {
  return *ptr;
}

void put_value_to_address(int val, int* ptr) {
  *ptr = val;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {  
  int* ptr;
  put_value_to_address(400, ptr);
  printf("value in address is %d\n", get_address_value(ptr));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `ptr` defined?

Comment: @JackWilliams I forget to define the ptr when editing the post. I did define it in the program. Sorry about the confusing.

Comment: So the answers are correct but also you should enable compiler warnings because when i ran this my compiler gave me a warning telling me ptr was being used uninitialized in main()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an uninitialized pointer. Accessing that pointer causes undefined behavior. In your case, the undefined behavior manifests as segmentation fault/error.

You need to make sure that `ptr` points to something valid before changing the value of what it points to in `put_value_to_address`.

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

or

```
int i;
int* ptr = &i;
```

If you use `malloc`, make sure to deallocate the memory. Add

```
free(ptr);
```

before the end of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `ptr` is uninitialized, to it contains a garbage value.  That means that it points to arbitrary memory address, which you might not be able to write to.  That is what is causing the Segmentation Fault.